# Git: keep two locations of the same file in sync

Tags: python, c++, git, synchronization, symlink

I have a git repo for a single-header C/C++ library that has a certain `.h` file in the root. That's where the main code lives. Now I want to make some bindings for other programming languages like Python or Node.js. I would like to put each bindings in its own subfolder. Now the catch is that during publishing only this very subfolder is published. The `.h` file (located a few levels up and included by a relative path) is not published, and this breaks the installation of the bindings for almost every language.

I can see the following options:

1. Symlinks. This is very close to what I need, but they might be problematic on certain file systems, so I'd like to know if there are any reasonable alternatives.
2. Hardlinks. AFAIK, not supported by Git at all.
3. Git hook to ensure that files in the subfolders match the one at the top level, and update them if needed. But since Git hooks are not tracked by Git - some developers may omit the hooks and break it.
4. A script to manually sync files. Pretty much like Git hooks, but more explicit. Might also allow to keep different versions of the `.h` file in different subfolders, and it would allow to update one bindings and not update the others for some time in the case of urgency. Maybe should come with a server-side hook or CI script to ensure the files match when tagged commit is pushed (e.g. when new version is released).

What do you think would be the preferred solution, or are there any unnoticed pitfalls I have missed?

Comment: To me it sounds like the main repository could be used as a submodule in a separate bindings repository. This would also allow the use case you describe in 4 (i.e. explicit updates), but it'd move the header into a subdirectory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use symlinks if you aren't planning to use this on Windows.

Don't use hooks or other approaches to copy the file in git, because then you have an unnecessary *versioned* copy that can get out of sync, unless you (as you mention) expect to need it to be deliberately out of sync.

What I would recommend is to fix the root problem: “during publishing only this very subfolder is published”. What you need is a **build process** that *copies the file where it is needed for the bindings to work,* and then “publishes” the result. This can be a simple script or Makefile that copies the file and then does the "publish" operation. (Be sure to add the copy to .gitignore so it isn't accidentally added!)